# can function test be called integration test at the same?

Tags: testing

This is part of example.c from zlib. I initially want to convert this code into a unit test using check, but then I kind of get confused:

Are these tests below function tests? Or could they be called integration tests or unit tests as well?

```
test_compress(compr, comprLen, uncompr, uncomprLen);
test_deflate(compr, comprLen);
test_inflate(compr, comprLen, uncompr, uncomprLen);
test_large_deflate(compr, comprLen, uncompr, uncomprLen);
test_large_inflate(compr, comprLen, uncompr, uncomprLen);
test_flush(compr, &comprLen);
test_sync(compr, comprLen, uncompr, uncomprLen);
comprLen = uncomprLen;
test_dict_deflate(compr, comprLen);
test_dict_inflate(compr, comprLen, uncompr, uncomprLen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unit test can actually be also an integration test. If your unit under test accesses external resources, then it's a traditional integration test. If it accesses other units, it's cosidered by many as a form of integration test as well (inter-module, not to confuse with inter-component/service/database integration). The latter is the case you are showing -- functions compute things that others then consume and further transform.

If the purpose of the test is to target a specific unit (e.g. function) but incidentally tests other units, then it also qualifies as an integration test. If, however, no other functions are exercised other than the intended target of the test (using stubs or mocks for auxiliary functions if needed) then it's just a unit test -- not an integration test. Nothing wrong with either approach; it all depends on the level of control and width of scope you intend to achieve. The fewer the units called, the more control you get but the smaller scope you test.

Comment: It really makes sense to me. Thanks

Comment: The answer is good enough for me, unittest has very low traffic,I will just close this one